# iOS Build Error Using PayPal Mobile SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, paypal, cocoapods, aws-sdk

I have an iOS application that is referencing the AWS Mobile frameworks directly and several other libraries using CocoaPods.  The project builds fine and I am able to connect to AWS without issues.

However, when I add the 'PayPal-iOS-SDK' as an additional library to reference in the PodFile and run pod install I get several build/linker errors:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AWSSNSErrorDomain", referenced from:
  ___88-[AWSPushManager interceptApplication:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke239 in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSLambdaInvoker", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSCloudLogic.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNS", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSGetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSubscribeInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSUnsubscribeInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSGoogleSignInProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove the -ObjC flag from the Other Linker Flags build setting I can build but cannot reference the PayPal framework as it depends on this setting.

I have also tried using -force_load instead of -ObjC but have not been successful in getting this to build either.

I looked at integrating PayPal via a direct reference instead of using CocoaPods but the -ObjC flag is still required for that type of integration and this results in the same errors as above.

Any ideas on using the AWS Mobile SDK in the same project as the PayPal iOS SDK?

Comment: Hi, could you share the force_load setting which you have tried? What target did you set the force_load for?

Comment: There must have been some other changes I had made while troubleshooting that interfered with the force_load setting.  I reverted all the changes and added the following: -force_load $(SRCROOT)/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/Core/Frameworks/libPayPalMobile.a and now it is building!

Comment: great! glad to hear you made it working!

Comment: Thanks for getting me to try that again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the -ObjC other linker flag and add the following other linker flag:

```
-force_load $(SRCROOT)/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/Core/Frameworks/libPayPalMobile.a
```

Comment: In our own project linker flag Pod project linker flag ?